# Download pretrained ASVspoof model of SE-ResNet34

Tags: python, adversarial-attack

I want to use **SE-ResNet34 or SE-ResNet18, SE-ResNet50,**... pretrained model's file to serve to generate adversarial samples with PGD attack method. However, I can not find any public pretrained file.

Please help me and give me a link to download pretrained file.

Thanks in advance.

I try to find a pretrained file for ASVspoof2019 or ASVspoof2021 dataset